# Could you power a complete circuit using a Dc-Dc boost inverting IC?

Tags: inverter, buck-boost

I was making a circuit, and i was limited to using one Dc-Dc boost inverting IC, with a power supply of 3.8V.
I used the Dc-Dc to make -5V on its output, and (if i change the polarity of its output) i can use these 5V to power everything i needed, and i was fine until here.

The issue is, how can i have a common Ground point with my 3.8V power supply?

[image]

the reason i want a common GND point with my power supply, is that, if i use a POWER mosfet to control another circuit (led array for example), the voltage i send to the Gate of the Mosfet, cannot activate it.

Side note:(Also when i try to activate the gate of the mosfet, the voltage on the Microcontroller increases to 5.3V)

Comment: It is unclear to how you're connecting the modules and what you're trying to achieve. I suggest drawing a **proper** schematic using the schematic drawing tool that is available when you edit the question. Then draw the modules using a symbol but add the names of the pins on the module (like GND, VCC). Also: you mention -5 V from the DCDC yet it is unclear where that voltage is in your drawing. Try to avoid using multiple GNDs where there is 5 V (for example) between them. You will confuse everyone and yourself. -5 V is -5 V so call it - 5 V and not "GND of module XYZ".

Comment: *Could you power a complete circuit using a Dc-Dc boost inverting IC?* Sure I can, as long as the "complete circuit" uses less current than the inverting DCDC boost converter can deliver, my circuit just sees "a supply" and will work. Your real question is: "How do I power my circuit from an inverting DCDC boost converter?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i have a common Ground point with my 3.8V power supply?

A cheap (but low-power) solution is to use a buck converter in an inverting buck-boost configuration.

[image]

You can also find chips specifically designed for inverting buck-boost topology.

Or isolated converters (forward, flyback, ...) that allow the output ground to be connected arbitrarily relative to the input ground (including connecting the output positive terminal to the input negative terminal).

If you are strictly bound to use a certain regulator IC designed for boost operation, you can probably use it to build a flyback inverter:

[image]

([image source and more information](http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/slyy062/slyy062.pdf))

With this isolated design you can make a negative output by simply swapping the Vout and output ground connections.

> if i use a POWER mosfet to control another circuit (led array for example), the voltage i send to the Gate of the Mosfet, cannot activate it.

Another option, rather than changing your power supply circuit, is use optocouplers or relays to connect control signals from one ground domain to the other.